# (Javascript prompt app ) switchcase inside switchcase will not run

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, switch-statement, infinite-loop

I am making an app (idk what to call it) that shows up as a prompt and alert.

However, my code seems to unable to run a switchcase inside a switchcase which I use to add an order into a cart and also use to show the content of the cart.

Another way of saying what my problem is:

1. I cannot add items to my cart
2. I cannot access my cart (the prompt just closes itself)

To be more clear I will include my code below along with a codepen link of it and I will comment where I think the problems are.

All input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
arrayCart =[];
totalBill = parseInt(0);
cartContent = arrayCart.length;

for(;;)
    {
        userInput = parseInt(prompt('1. Menu\n2. Your Cart\n3. Payment\n4. Exit'))
        switch(userInput)
        {
            // This is to go to Menu
            case 1:
                inputPesanan = prompt('Silahkan pilih menu yang diinginkan:\n1. Paket Bento A\n2. Paket Bento B\n3. Paket Bento C')


// I think the 1st problem starts here
                switch(inputPesanan)
                { 
                case 1:
                arrayCart.push('Paket Bento A - Rp20.000\n');
                totalBill += parseInt(20000);
                break;

                case 2:
                arrayCart.push('Paket Bento B - Rp25.000\n');
                totalBill += parseInt(25000);
                break;

                case 3:
                arrayCart.push('Paket Bento C - Rp30.000\n');
                totalBill += parseInt(30000);
                break;
            }
            break;
            // and the 1st problem ends here

        // This is to check the Cart's content
        case 2:
            // And I think the 2nd problem starts here
            inputKeranjang = alert('Isi Keranjang Anda\n' + arrayCart + '\n\n' + 'Total Tagihan Anda: \n' + totalBIll)   
            break;
            // and it ends here

//----------- everything under this line seems to be working fine ---------------------------------------

        // This is to input how much money you would like to pay with and calculate the change or deficit (if any)
        case 3:    
            inputPayment = parseInt(prompt('Total Tagihan Anda :\nRp' + totalBill + '\n\nBerapa uang yang Anda akan bayarkan?'));
            switch(true)
            {
                case inputPayment<totalBill:
                alert('Uang Anda kurang sebesar Rp ' + parseInt(totalBill-inputPayment));
                break;

                case inputPayment>totalBill:
                alert('Anda akan mendapat kembalian sebesar Rp' + parseInt(inputPayment-totalBill));
                break;

                case inputPayment=totalBill:
                alert('Uang Anda pas');
                break;
            }
            break;
    }

    // This is to end the infinite loop and close the app
    if(userInput === 4)
    {
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch(true) will not work, neither will case inputPayment>total bill. Case will only work on constants

Comment: I have changed my program to use if else statements and it works! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the javascript developer but as far switch statement goes,

This is how it works:

1. The switch expression is evaluated once.
2. The value of the expression is compared with the values of each case.
3. If there is a match, the associated block of code is executed.

So whatever you pass as input to the switch("YouInput") it checks for that in all cases, so If you pass Int as your Input in first switch, let say 1 then case 1: will execute if you pass 100 case 100: if no case match default will and if you pass String let say "Yosia" then if there is any case "Yosia": that will execute

So in your second switch cases you are checking for case 1: , case:2  but I don't think your "inputPesanan" is of type int beacuse in everywhere else you are using some parseIn but not there so may be print and check you "inputPesanan" it will not be 1, 2, or cases you are looking for.

Comment: I have changed my program to use if else statements and it works! Many thanks!!